# FHIR: Nested extensions

Tags: hl7-fhir

What is the correct representation of a multi-level FHIR extension?

```
<extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth">
   <extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth.type">
      <valueCode value="local" />
   </extension>
   <extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth.flag>
      <valueBoolean value="true" />
   </extension>
</extension>
```

-- OR --

```
<extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth">
   <extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth#type">
      <valueCode value="local" />
   </extension>
   <extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth#flag>
      <valueBoolean value="true" />
   </extension>
</extension>
```

In the StructureDefinition, should the URL for the sub-extensions be fully qualified (url: "http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth#type") or just the name ("type") as here: http://hl7-fhir.github.io/extension-goal-relationship.html

Finally, is there an standard linkage between StructureDefinition.name and the sub-extension URL? I.e. the part after the # (type in http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth#type) should match the name in the structure defition of the extension:

```
<StructureDefinition>
   ...
      <element>
         <path value="Extension" />
         <name value="researchAuth" />
      </element>
      <element>
         <path value="Extension.extension" />
         <name value="researchAuth.type" />
      </element>
    ...
</StructureDefinition>
```

Otherwise, how does one determine what the post # element is??

James's example adds to my confusion:
http://jamesagnew.github.io/hapi-fhir/doc_extensions.html

In the sub-extensions section, the "parent" is "http://example.com#parent" and the children are "http://example.com#ChildOne" and "http://example.com#ChildTwo" respectively.

I would expect only "http://example.com" for the parent extension (no # as it's the base extension defined at the URL).  OR http://example.com#parent.ChildOne for the sub-extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DSTU 1, it would be the first approach.  In DSTU 2, it would be this:

```
<extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth">
   <extension url="type">
      <valueCode value="local" />
   </extension>
   <extension url="flag>
      <valueBoolean value="true" />
   </extension>
</extension>
```

That only holds for children of complex extensions.  If you want to include an extension defined elsewhere inside another extension, you need to use the full URL.

Comment: How do I match "flag" to the StructureDefinition?  What's the StructureDefinition look like?  <type><profile value="flag" /></type>??

Comment: Also, url can't be a "uri" type then...it would need to be a string.

Comment: The structure definition would slice "extension" and assert a fixed value of "flag" for the "url" element.  You can see an example of the StructureDefinition for a complex extension here: http://hl7-fhir.github.io/extension-goal-target.xml.html

Comment: flag is a relative uri, which is legal for the uri type

Comment: So what's the absolute URL of a nested extension?  http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth/local in this example?

Comment: http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth#local

(Though it should really be http://example.com/StructureDefinition/researchAuth#local)

Comment: isn't this a departure from the normal relative to absolute URL construction? Also, in a 3 level nest, we start to dot like this, correct? `example.com/StructureDefinition/researchAuth#local.part`

Comment: It is a departure, but realistically it's not a true "relative URL".  The address isn't being expressed with respect to the containing resource, only with respect to the value of an element in the parent URL.

And yes, for additional levels, the separator is with "."